# jQuery offset() returns null

Tags: jquery, offset

Why does my code not return the top and left values?
Instead returns null. Does there need to be some values set already for offset(); to work?

```
var divOrg = $( "#portfolioButton" );
var pos = divOrg.offset();
console.log( "left : " + pos.left + ", top : " + pos.top );
```

Comment: Does `#portfolioButton` exist?

Comment: Is this - `#portfolioButton` - correctly written? Is this how it appears in the html? Apart from something similar to this, there's no reason why the code won't run: http://jsfiddle.net/SPG33/

Comment: Is there text in the button?

Comment: This is my div for portfolio id: `<div id="portfolioButton" onMouseOver="OverStateMenu(this)" class="menuClass menuClassOverState shadow1px">` @ExplosionPills yes it exists @JOPLOmacedo I do have similar but not with the same id, the id is unique. @BlakePlumb yes there is some text in this div, would that affect it. Thanks guys!

Comment: instead, try `console.log(divOrg);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine as long as the `div` is not hidden. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRUuL/3/)

```
<div id="portfolioButton">text</div>
```

You don't need to set any values for `offset()` to work. It gets its values from the position of the element relative to the document.

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an
>   element 
>       relative to the document.

Comment: I understand enough jQuery to understand the offset() principle, it seems straightforward. This is the error I get in the console log: `TypeError: pos is null`. Thanks again.

Comment: I also have multiple classes applied to this div, would that affect it in some way?

Comment: There is 3 class applied to this div `.menuClass{
 width:auto;
 vertical-align:middle;
 display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
 height:30px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;
}
.menuClassOverState{
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color:rgba(153,153,153,1);
 position:absolute;
}.shadow1px{
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}` Sorry looks pretty messy in this text box.

Comment: Well I tried your css and it still seems to be working for me. I did notice that you were applying both a `position: relative` and a `position: absolute` to the `div` though.

Comment: I have since retrieved the position: absolute, thanks for your help, will let you know how I get on.

Comment: I checked all my code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRUuL/3/) and found nothing wrong, very strange.

Comment: The last thought I have is what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1 import from here //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

try this in the head of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

     var divOrg = $( "#portfolioButton" );

        var offset = divOrg.offset();
        divOrg.html ("left : " + offset.left + ", top : " + offset.top );

 console.log(divOrg)
});
    </script>
```

And in the body:`<div id="portfolioButton">Test1.</div>`

reference: http://api.jquery.com/offset/